# Jquery ajax SOAP no response

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, soap, wsdl

I do not know what exactly happening with me. I am trying to call soap service but im not getting any response.

```
function soap_call(){     
    var wsUrl = "https://ws.cert.transactionexpress.com/portal/merchantframework/MerchantWebServices-v1?wsdl";
    var soapRequest = 
        '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://postilion/realtime/merchantframework/xsd/v1/"> \
          <SOAP-ENV:Body> \
            <v1:UpdtRecurrProfRequest> \
                 <v1:merc> \
                    <v1:id>7777778598</v1:id> \
                    <v1:regKey>BLHP7DK5W385J6WZ</v1:regKey> \
                    <v1:inType>1</v1:inType> \
                    <v1:prodType>5</v1:prodType> \
                 </v1:merc> \
                 <v1:cust> \
                    <v1:type>0</v1:type> \
                    <v1:contact> \
                       <v1:fullName>Test Person</v1:fullName> \
                       <v1:addrLn1>123 Main</v1:addrLn1> \
                       <v1:addrLn2>Second Floor</v1:addrLn2> \
                       <v1:city>Gilbert</v1:city> \
                       <v1:state>AZ</v1:state> \
                       <v1:zipCode>85296</v1:zipCode> \
                       <v1:type>1</v1:type> \
                       <v1:stat>1</v1:stat> \
                    </v1:contact> \
                    <v1:pmt> \
                       <v1:type>0</v1:type> \
                       <v1:card> \
                          <v1:pan>4485896261017708</v1:pan> \
                          <v1:sec>999</v1:sec> \
                          <v1:xprDt>1602</v1:xprDt> \
                       </v1:card> \
                       <v1:ordNr>Cust Ref ID  Can be used for extra info</v1:ordNr> \
                       <v1:desc>Can be used to name wallet again</v1:desc> \
                       <v1:indCode>2</v1:indCode> \
                    </v1:pmt> \
                 </v1:cust> \
              </v1:UpdtRecurrProfRequest> \
          </SOAP-ENV:Body> \
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>' ;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: wsUrl,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapRequest,
            //processData: false,
            //async:true,
            headers: {
                SOAPAction: "UpdtRecurrProf"
            },
            complete: function (xmlHttpRequest) {
                alert(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML);
            },

        });

    }
```

I tried to call using [this link](http://wsdlbrowser.com/soapclient?wsdl_url=https%3A%2F%2Fws.cert.transactionexpress.com%2Fportal%2Fmerchantframework%2FMerchantWebServices-v1%3Fwsdl&function_name=UpdtRecurrProf) , then it gave me correct response.

I do not have expertise in soap. I will appreciate if anyone can help me out from here.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked your request with a [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) - there's everything absolutely fine with a request itself. Here's the response I had:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:UpdtRecurrProfResponse xmlns="http://postilion/realtime/portal/soa/xsd/Faults/2009/01" xmlns:ns2="http://postilion/realtime/merchantframework/xsd/v1/">
            <ns2:custId>1450956517822188336</ns2:custId>
            <ns2:pmtId>1450956517853193808</ns2:pmtId>
            <ns2:rspCode>00</ns2:rspCode>
        </ns2:UpdtRecurrProfResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

The problem appears because of you use javascript and [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) doesn't allow you to request domains, which are different from yours - this helps to protect from XSS attacks.

It could be possible to request remote host though, if it provides a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) header, like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, which allows all domains to request it, but looking at the response, it does not return this header it this case:

```
Cache-Control → private
Content-Encoding → gzip
Content-Type → text/xml;charset=utf-8
Date → Thu, 24 Dec 2015 11:28:37 GMT
Server → WebServer
Transfer-Encoding → chunked
```

Also you should see this error message in your browser console, which approves my suggestion.

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource

So the problem is not with SOAP request itself, but with that you try to request it via javascript. Make a request through on your backend (PHP for instance) - and it should go smoothly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For PCI compilance I need to call it from javascript. From the server side its working. But i need to do it with javascript.